# Print "Information Cont..." in Jasper report if text is big and continues in the next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using IReport 4.1.3 to design my report, and I am quite new to IReport.  There is a requirement in the report:  If the dynamic text size is big and continues in a new page, it should print "XXX Continue..." in the first row of the new page.  I haven't figured out how to do that.  Can some experts provide some suggestions?  For example, the first page may look like:

---

**Chapter One**

blahblahblah......
blahblahblah......

### blahblahblah......

Then the 2nd page should look like:

---

**Chapter One Continue...**

blahblahblah......
blahblahblah......

### blahblahblah......